# What is the better way to stop currently running job in quartz scheduler?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz Scheduler .I want to stop currently running job.
    I am using this one in a web application .When I click on start button then job execution is started but when I want to stop this executing job using stop button .
    But I am not able to stop.
    Please give me an idea how can I stop currently running job?

```
I am giving my code.

//when i click on start button then this class will call.



@WebServlet("/ScheduleController")
public class AscentScheduleController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String RANDOM = "random";

    Scheduler schedulerRecon;
    Scheduler schedulerPos;
    Scheduler schedulerFile;
    Scheduler schedulerEtl;
    Trigger triggerIris;
    JobKey jobKey;
    JobDetail job;
    String key;
    int time;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AscentScheduleController() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        try {

            String id = request.getParameter("id");

            System.out.println("hello in controller");
            System.out.println(id);

             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());



             schedulerRecon = new StdSchedulerFactory()
                .getScheduler();
        schedulerRecon.start();
        session.setAttribute(id,schedulerRecon );   
        System.out.println();// SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("controller schedil     "+schedulerRecon);

             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                jobKey = new JobKey("jobKeyIris", "group1");

                job = JobBuilder.newJob(DemoTrgger.class).withIdentity("jobKey").build();

                triggerIris = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("triggerIris", "group1").startNow()  
                        .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60).// repeatForever()).build();
                        withRepeatCount(0)).build();
                session.setAttribute("job", jobKey);
                System.out.println();// SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("controller job key    "+jobKey);
                // temp=temp+temp;
                schedulerRecon.scheduleJob(job, triggerIris);
                // scheduler.scheduleJob(jobQCB, triggerQCB);
                System.out.println("fire job");

        }
}       
//and my job class which implement Job is below


public class DemoTrgger implements Job {
public static Thread th;
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("demo trigger  "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"thread obj  "+Thread.currentThread());
        th = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println();
        for(long i=0l;i<2000000;i++){
            System.out.println("i---------  "+i);
        }
        for(long i=0l;i<2000000l;i++){
            System.out.println("j---  "+i);
        }
    }


}


when I click on stop button the below class will call.Here I get the Scheduler reference which I use in start using session and I want stop respectively running job.

@WebServlet("/SchedulerStopController")
public class SchedulerStopController extends HttpServlet implements InterruptableJob {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SchedulerStopController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        Scheduler schedular=(Scheduler) session.getAttribute(id);
        System.out.println();// SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("stop schedular   "+schedular);


        try {
            SchedulerMetaData metaData = schedular.getMetaData();
        } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
       // log.info("Executed " + metaData.getNumberOfJobsExecuted() + " jobs.");

        /*Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                // this will get called on shutdown

// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("------- My own shutdown hook -----------------");
            }
        });
    */




        try {
            JobKey jobKey=(JobKey) session.getAttribute("job");
            System.out.println();// SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("stop controller "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("stop job   "+jobKey);
            schedular.deleteJob(jobKey);


        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    thanks.
```